# How can I check if a list in a list comprehension inside a dictionary comprehension is empty?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I'm currently using list comprehension inside dictionary comprehension to detect changes between 2 dictionaries with lists as values.

The code looks something like this:

```
detectedChanges = {table: [field for field in tableDict[table] if field not in fieldBlackList] for table in modifiedTableDict if table not in tableBlackList}
```

This will create a dictionary where each entry is the table name and associated with it is a list changes.

The problem I'm getting is that although this code works, the resulting structure *detectedChanges* is filled with entries that only contain a table name and an empty list (meaning that no changes were detected).

I'm currently doing a posterior sweep through the dictionary in order to remove these entries but I would like avoid putting them in the dictionary in the first place.

Basically if I could somehow do a length check or something over `[field for field in tableDict[table]` I could validade it before creating the key:value entry.

Is there way to do this with the current method I'm using?

Comment: I'm not sure I have understood what you want to do; however: have you considered using a `for` loop instead of dictionary comprehension? Your code would be much more readable.

Comment: Wow ... That's some comprehension you got there.  Honestly, I find what you have quite hard to read, and anything that you cook up to remove particular fields is only going to make it _harder_ to read.  Personally, I'd unravel the whole thing into a loop and then your checks become really easy...

Comment: I believe I understand the comprehension, and your problem. I third @AndreaCorbellini's suggestion to write out a proper `for` loop. You have a little more power that way, ex. Using `continue` to skip adding rows that would be empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an addition to [eumiro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28326309/786020). Please use their answer first as it is more readable. However, if I'm not mistaken comprehensions are in general faster, so there is one use case, but *ONLY IF THIS IS A BOTTLENECK IN YOUR CODE*. I cannot emphasize that enough.

```
detectedChanges = {table: [field for field in tableDict[table]
                           if field not in fieldBlackList]
                   for table in modifiedTableDict
                   if table not in tableBlackList
                   if set(tableDict[table])-set(fieldBlackList)}
```

Notice how ugly this is. I enjoy doing things like this to get a better understanding of Python, and due to the fact that I have had things like this be bottlenecks before. However, you should always [use profiling](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) before trying to solve issues that may not exist.

The addition to your code `[...] if set(tableDict[table])-set(fieldBlackList) [...]` creates a set of the entries in the current table, and a set of the blacklisted fields and gets the entries that are in the current table but not the blacklist. Empty sets evaluate to `False` causing the comprehension to ignore that table, the same as if it were in the `tableBlackList` variable. To make it more explicit, one could compare the result to an empty set or check whether it has a value in it at all.

Also, prefer the following for speed:

```
detectedChanges = {table: [field for field in fields
                           if field not in fieldBlackList]
                   for table, fields in modifiedTableDict.iteritems()
                   if table not in tableBlackList
                   if set(fields)-set(fieldBlackList)}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was it. 
I was trying to do everything in 1 line as an exercise. My code actually has a lot more if clauses and comprehensions than the sample I posted here so doing everything in 1 line will make it impossible to understand. Using a format like in eumiro's answer will make the code much more readable. Despite being lightly slower.

Answer (score 1):

Although dict comprehensions are cool, they should not be misused. The following code is not much longer and it can be kept on a narrow screen as well:

```
detectedChanges = {}
for table, fields in modifiedTableDict.iteritems():
    if table not in tableBlackList:
        good_fields = [field for field in fields
                             if field not in fieldBlackList]
        if good_fields:
            detectedChanges[table] = good_fields
```

Comment: I think `[field for field in fields if field not in fieldBlackList]` looks like you want a set difference, i.e. if `fields` and `fieldBlackList` are both sets then you could have `good_fields = list(fields - fieldBlackList)`.

Comment: Yes, this seems like a better solution. But just out of curiosity, isn't there a way to achieve what I wanted in 1 line?

Comment: @Duolasa. Yes there is. Was there something wrong with my answer?